# C# LINQ: Projecting a detail object into a summary object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a .csv and the data looks like so:

```
Account,Debit,Credit

1,10.00,5.00

1,10.00,10.00

2,5.00,5.00

2,10.00,10.00
```

This data populates an `IEnumerable<Source>`. The definition is below:

```cs
public class Detail {

  public string Account {get; set;}
  public decimal Debit {get; set;}
  public decimal Credit {get; set;}

}
```

I am attempting to consolidate and project this "detail" object into a summarized object where Total is the sum of debits and credits per account.

```cs
public class Summary {

  public string Account {get; set;}
  public decimal Total {get; set;}

}
```

The end result I'm shooting for is a distinct list of accounts which have all debits and credits rolled up per account, so that instead of multiple lines per account/debit/credit, I have a summary projection.

```
Account,Debit,Credit


1,5.00,0.00 

2, 0.00, 0.00
```

Let's say `detailrecords` is a populated collection of type `IEnumerable<Detail>`.

```cs
var results = detailrecords
      .GroupBy(x => x.Account)
      .Select(c => new Summary() {
          Account = ?? I can't figure out how to access my detail properties here 
          Total = ?? I am not sure how to perform arithmetic without access to detail properties
      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
var results = detailRecords
        .GroupBy(x => x.Account)
        .Select(c => new Summary
        {
            Account = c.Key,
            Total = c.Sum(y => y.Credit + y.Debit)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: @MikeM Awesome!